# Method of displaying message dialogs

Tags: c#, testing, dependency-injection

I have a collection of programs that repeatedly display messages to the user for various reasons.  My initial thought for this, was a basic static helper method(s):

```
public class Message
{        
    public static void ShowMessage(...)
    {
        ...
```

The method itself does various things (i.e. it isn't just a wrapper for `MessageBox.Show()`).

Obviously, this creates a problem for testing.  So the next solution that springs to mind is using a singleton pattern.

I'm sure the neatest way is dependency injection, but that presents the problem of having to instantiate a new stateless object each time I want to display a message.

So my target is to create a structure that allows a single call to a common class.

```
Message.ShowMessage("hello");
```

Is there a way to achieve this simply while maintaining testability?

Comment: `but that presents the problem of having to instantiate a new stateless object each time I want to display a message` - That is not true at all, it all depends on the lifetime scope you specify when you register the object in your container.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be using strategy pattern (which might be a bit of an overkill depending on the size of the project).

```
interface IMessageShowingStrategy 
{
    void ShowMessage(...)
}

class RealMessageShowingStrategy : IMessageShowingStrategy 
{
    void ShowMessage(...) 
    {
        // Real code
    }
}

class TestingMessageShowingStrategy : IMessageShowingStrategy
{
    void ShowMessage(...)
    {
        // Code used for testing
    }
}

class Message 
{
    IMessageShowingStrategy messageStrategy;

    void ShowMessage(...)
    {
        this.messageStrategy.ShowMessage(...);
    }

}
```

Then you can choose which strategy to use. For testing, you can use an instance of `TestingMessageShowingStrategy` (maybe when the application is started with a -debug switch or something) and otherwise use the Real strategy. This is what I've been using for Unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by simply extending the form class and creating methods as you required.